# jQuery to change direction of CSS keyframe animation midway through

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Curious to know if there is a way to use jQuery to reverse the direction of a CSS keyframe animation mid way - not to restart the first point.

Here is the current code for infinite / alternating panorama scroll where it will alternate the direction if you click the image. It will simply replace the class and restart the animation from the start.

However, my goal is to be able to change the direction midway through when clicked. Any tips is greatly appreciated.

http://jsfiddle.net/JQjGZ/210/

CSS:

```
#panorama-scroll {
width: 100%;
height: 512px;
margin: 0;
background: url(https://c2.staticflickr.com/2/1519/24649255286_03bb5ab0e3_b.jpg) repeat-x;
}

#panorama-scroll.forward {
 -webkit-animation: backgroundScroll 15s linear infinite;
-moz-animation: backgroundScroll 15s linear infinite;
animation: backgroundScroll 15s linear infinite;

}

@-webkit-keyframes backgroundScroll {
from {background-position: 0 0;}
to {background-position: -1024px 0;}
}
@-moz-keyframes backgroundScroll {
from {background-position: 0 0;}
to {background-position: -1024px 0;}
}
@keyframes backgroundScroll {
from {background-position: 0 0;}
to {background-position: -1024px 0;}
}

#panorama-scroll.reverse {
-webkit-animation: backgroundScrollreverse 15s linear infinite;
-moz-animation: backgroundScrollreverse 15s linear infinite;
animation: backgroundScrollreverse 15s linear infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes backgroundScrollreverse {
from {background-position: 0 0;}
to {background-position: 1024px 0;}
}
@-moz-keyframes backgroundScrollreverse {
from {background-position: 0 0;}
to {background-position: 1024px 0;}
}
@keyframes backgroundScrollreverse {
from {background-position: 0 0;}
to {background-position: 1024px 0;}
}
```

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var content = $('#panorama-scroll');

$('#panorama-scroll').live('click', function() {
    $(this).toggle(function() {
        content.removeClass('forward').addClass('reverse');
    }, function() {
        content.removeClass('reverse').addClass('forward');
    }).trigger('click');
});
});
```

Comment: Why don't you try to do this with plain CSS keyframing if it doesn't include any type of behavior change over time?

Comment: @Sqnkov thx although I'm not sure I follow. Is there a way to use keyframes to change direction midway without starting over from the first position? That would be great. Currently I haven't found a way to do that without making it start from the first key frame as you can see in the sample. Have tried reverse, alternate, etc. I did see a way to do this with transform rotate but not with x,y to x,y

Comment: I though You were fully-aware of the keyframe syntax so I skipped to my final thought, sorry for that.

Comment: @Sqnkov, here is an example which I hope helps my intention: http://codepen.io/Zeaklous/pen/sFnyD - please note how it reverses direction from when you hover - not from the 0 degree mark. I have tried various methods but I've only been able to achieve this with transform: rotate for the time being...

Answer (score 0):

Your current animation states use the "from" and "to" declarations, which is not really practical when You get down to creating some funky animated action. What you need is variation, not linear completion.

What you can try to do is use [**percentage values**](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/keyframe-animation-syntax/) for animation states.

This is Your code now:

```
@-webkit-keyframes backgroundScroll {
 from {background-position: 0 0;}
 to {background-position: -1024px 0;}
}
```

It should be something like this if you want it to change direction mid-way trough:

```
@-webkit-keyframes backgroundScroll {
 0% {background-position: 0 0;}
 50% {background-position: -512px 0;}
 100% {background-position: 0 0;}
}
```

To change the direction of your CSS animation state, you need to use `animation-play-state`. After that you can simply apply some jQuery actions to it as you wish.

There is a thorough explanation about what I am referring to **[here.](http://tympanus.net/codrops/css_reference/animation-play-state/)**

Comment: Thanks in advance for your help! I think my explanation was very poor and has caused confusion. Please allow me to elaborate: My hope is if someone clicks the image (or directional arrows eventually) it will make the infinitely scrolling panorama go the other direction. Currently, it will reverse the direction but starts from the first point. My hope is it will change direction at the coordinates you clicked. Example: if it scrolls 200px to the left and you click, it will reverse from 200px point and go the other direction from that point. Not from 0. Hope this helps sorry for confusion

Comment: @Chumtarou , please take a look at my edited answer above.

Comment: thank you - I had been trying animation play state and although I can pause it, changing the direction from that coordinate is still a mystery. Perhaps I may need to do this fully with Jquery. Will keep trying. Thx again in the meantime.

Comment: One more thing, @Chumtarou. You can try and use Velocity.js for the purpose. There was a preset for that somewhere.